# Divide Cell value by n, then split the values across n cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro that lets me split a persons monthly schedule into weeks.

```
Sub HoursSplit()
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/4"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]"
End Sub
```

As an example:

| Person | Month 2 | Month 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | 173 | 173 |

Effectively:

- I select the monthly hours im looking to split (i.e Month 2)
- copy it
- select a cell elsewhere with no data in it
- Hit Cntrl + Shift + C

In the case above, it gives me

| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43.25 | 43.25 | 43.25 | 43.25 |

Thing is, this only works for a single person/cell, making splitting everyones hourshours up into weeks tedious.

How can i modify the above to work for an entire column range selection (i.e Multiple people at once for the same month)?

Comment: Just wondering what you will do after December, when you have reached 48 weeks and find out that there are actually 52 / 53 weeks per year.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Hi Tom, yes i'm well aware of this. We typically work on a 4.33 Weeks per month basis. But for this excercise, it was just important to split the data as fast as possible then have the individuals responsible for their segments of data to swap it out themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can do what you want (and should be faster).

```
Public Sub HoursSplit_Test()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Resize(, 4).Value = cell.Value / 4
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer as the correct one. Its definitely faster.

Comment: @Krono Just to elaborate why that's the case - reading/writing cell is very expensive process to do so it's better to interact with cells as little as possible. Your solution has 6 actions (1 read, 1 write + 1 copy on the original `cell`  and 3 paste/write on the 3 cells to the right) for each cell while my solution has 2-3 actions (1 read from `cell`,1 resize and 1 write).

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve my own issue eventually.

```
Public Sub HoursSplit_Test()
Dim cell As Excel.Range

For Each cell In Selection
    cell.Value = cell.Value / 4
    cell.Copy

    cell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
    cell.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial
    cell.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial

    Next cell
End Sub
```